# How do I make Outlook 2007 download all messages from the IMAP server?

Tags: gmail, microsoft-outlook-2007, download, imap

I am trying to get my gmail mail into Outlook 2007 via its IMAP connector.

It seems that Outlook 2007 only downloads the message headers, not the email messages and not the attachments, unless you specifically click on a message.

How do I make Outlook 2007 download all messages from the IMAP server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you drag all the folders off the IMAP server to a local folder, outlook will download all the messages and store them locally. Keep in mind this will also remove those messages from the IMAP server.

Comment: Is there a way to just copy it instead of moving them?

Comment: You could try copying the messages to the local store. The result should be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Outlook 2007 also has a means to change the default delivery location of the messages.

Go to Tools -> Account Settings - >  Email Tab

Click on the change folder button and change the delivery location to the local Personal Folders Inbox and click OK.

You should be good to go after this. All of your mail will be saved to your local PST instead of requiring you to move the messages manually.

Answer (score 0):

no, this does not exist for IMAP
for POP3, tyes the button is there to 'change folder' and redirect to another delivery folder; unfortunately, for IMAP, that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Options -> Mail Setup -> Send/Receive... -> Edit... -> Choose the option to download complete items including attachments for subscribed folders on the account of your choice. IMAP or POP3